# REACT-SELECT: Is there a way to declare 'selected' in options?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to declare 'selected' in options array,
and this 'selected' item will be displayed by default?

```
<Select onChange={this.changeUser}
 options={[{value:1,labe:1},
           {value:2,label:2,selected},
           {value:3,label:3}]}
/>
```

Comment: you can set the default value of the items you are selecting in state...so that when the component mounts you have an intial state value then the value as value on react-select  ``<Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={value} // set this
        onChange={onchangefunc}
        options={[
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        ]}
      />``

Comment: see an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/32pwzwxom?file=/index.js:1364-1376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) you can set a default selected value as `value` in state which you can update when the user switches to an alternate option using the `onChange` handler

Take a look at this example from the docs

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: {value: 'one', label: 'One'},
  }
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption }); // this will update the state of selected therefore updating value in react-select
    console.log(`Selected: ${selectedOption.label}`); 
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    const value = selectedOption && selectedOption.value; // this will read from state and set the value in state as the selected value. Therefore setting a value even when none has yet to be selected.

    return (
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={value} // so here the default value of one will be set then updates during the on change event
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={[
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Set a selected value in the `state` the set the value of this option as the `value` in react-select

Comment: where is the default I don't understand, from what you wrote i need to select some item, i need that by default it will be the second item

Comment: So the `value`  which you get in the intial state i.e `{value: 'one', label: 'One'}` its value will be set at the default value each time the component is mounted. So when you load up the page The label one will be selected

Comment: so in your case you would set the intial state to `{value:2,label:2}` Which would be the one thats selected. by default on component mount

Comment: So even when no value is selected react-select will read from state and set that value as the selected.

Comment: glad I could help